# Purpose of 1 kΩ resistor in parallel with load at output of op-amp

Tags: operational-amplifier, load

As I was reading some op-amp data sheets, I noticed they placed output resistors to ground in some test circuits. These can be seen in the insets of the plots below for the [LTC6228](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ltc6228-6229.pdf) and the [LT6202](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/620234fd.pdf).

What is the purpose of these resistors?

Under what conditions should I put a similar resistor in parallel with my load?

[image: Plot of op amp overshoot behavior from the LTC6228 datasheet.]
*Figure 1: Plot of op-amp overshoot behavior from the LTC6228 datasheet.*

[image: Plot of op amp settling behavior from the LT6202 datasheet.]
*Figure 2: Plot of op-amp settling behavior from the LT6202 datasheet.*

Answer (score 10):

The resistor ***is*** the load.

The idea is to test the op-amp under realistic loading conditions.

Comment: No, the 1kΩ resistor is not the load, or a sizable fraction of it! The bulk of the load is made by RS+CL.

Comment: @fgrieu Hmm, two meanings. In the sense of the load driven by the opamp, they are dominant only at frequencies above 1 / (2 pi R_S C_L), and below that it's the lone resistor.  In the sense of "what it's wired to for some purpose", it might represent a capacitive load (and the 1k might not even be present at all). [Not disagreeing with either of you *per se*, just to say better clarity is possible.]

Answer (score 6):

*Under what conditions should I put a similar resistor in parallel with my load?*

Only if you want to duplicate this test. The test guarantees that your design will work with a load this large or smaller.

Comment: So it does not provide a benefit to the circuit? And it is not required for stability, low noise, or linearity? Is it just showing that the device "works" with some given current draw/load?

Answer (score 5):

The output stages of these opamps are a complementary pair of BJTs, each in a common-emitter configuration. You will want *some* current drawn from the output to ensure linear performance. Adding a 1K or 500R resistor between the output and ground with ±5V supplies will draw ±5mA or ±10mA at full swing. If your circuit already draws a few milliamps into the load or feedback network at full swing then there's no point in adding that extra resistance.

Comment: This makes some sense, however there are plenty of examples where the output of an op-amp is directly driving a high impedance load (e.g. the non-inverting input of another op-amp). Will these designs suffer from a decrease in linearity?

Answer (score 2):

The output impedance of the opamp depends on the current it's supplying. Sometimes it's necessary to pull some current from the output to stably drive a capacitive load.

Answer (score 0):

The 1kohm load resistors shown need not be component resistors at all. They can represent the input resistance of the wideband oscilloscope that is used to measure the output overshoot. If the test is to be duplicated using an oscilloscope with 50 ohm input impedance then then add a 950 ohm resistor in series with the oscilloscope input and multiply its vertical display by 20.

Answer (score 0):

In order to determine the different parameters of a piece, manufacturing companies perform tests under certain test conditions.
By drawing the desired shape along with 1 kilo ohm resistance, the manufacturer informs the buyer that the parameter specified in the data sheet has been tested and obtained under what conditions.
In other words, if you want to test the desired parameter in the purchased part, you must test the circuit according to the figure provided in the  datasheet.

Comment: Hossein Ameri - Hi, Your answer has triggered our detection for being generated using AI e,.g. ChatGPT. How much help did you get from ChatGPT or similar? Please note that we do not want AI-generated answers here. Thanks.

Comment: @SamGibson-Hi, the answer is provided without using AI e,.g.  and completely based on my personal and technical experiences.

Comment: @HosseinAmeri - so you are saying that it is really only given in the drawing as a reference under which the testing was performed and may or may not have anything to do with circuit stability, noise levels, or linearity. Is that correct? And further, I should not worry about omitting these resistors from a design in which I am driving a device with a large input impedance, for instance the non-inverting input of an other op-amp?

Comment: @py_man - If you have noticed, the resistance of 1 kOhm is a large number compared to the load resistance, that is, a large amount of current will flow towards the load resistance, in the DC analysis, the role of the 1 kOhm resistance is more clear, when the capacitor is charged and from The DC analysis view is open circuit, the 1k ohm resistor connects the output of the op amp to the ground and somehow reduces the output noise.

Comment: @py_man - According to your statement that your input impedance is large, it is possible that when you do not have a signal at the input, the noises will affect the inputs and consequently the output of the circuit, so you need to cancel part of the noises. You will have to act according to the designed circuit.